# Latex equation in a plot

Tags: r, plot, r-markdown, knitr

I'm writing in rmarkdown to produce a html_document, I want to write a latex equation in the axis titles. 
Is there a way?

```
x <- c(0,1,1,1,2,2,2,3)
Fn <- ecdf(x)
plot(Fn , lwd = 2, main="",ylab = "$F(x)$",xlab="$x$",yaxt="n")
```

Comment: R has it's own syntax for such things. See the `?plotmath` help page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @MrFlick pointed out, there is a certain syntax for mathematical annotations. Sometimes it might not be enough due to complex formulas or certain symbols.

A way around this that avoids rendering a pdf plot (created using tikz) inside a pdf viewer inside the HTML document is converting it to another format.

Here I change the plot hook to convert the tikz pdf plot to png and include it using the original plot hook.

````
---
title: "Test"
output: html_document
---

```{r, include=F}
library(pdftools)
library(png)
library(knitr)
oldHook <- knit_hooks$get("plot")
knit_hooks$set(plot = function(x, options) {
  fname  <- gsub("pdf", "png", x)
  bitmap <- pdf_render_page(x, page = 1, dpi = 300)
  png::writePNG(bitmap, fname)
  oldHook(fname, options)
})
```


```{r, dev='tikz'}
x <- c(0,1,1,1,2,2,2,3)
Fn <- ecdf(x)
plot(Fn , lwd = 2, main="",ylab = "$F(x)$",xlab="$x$",yaxt="n")
```
````

[image]

Comment: Nice!  If you want SVG instead of PNG graphics, these lines in the plot hook should do it, assuming you have the `pdf2svg` utility:  `fname  <- sub("pdf$", "svg", x); system(paste("pdf2svg", x, fname, "all")); oldHook(fname, options)`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `latex2exp`

```
library(latex2exp)
plot(Fn , lwd = 2, main="",
     ylab = latex2exp("$F(x)$"),
     xlab=latex2exp("$x$"),yaxt="n")
```

Or in R Base

```
plot(Fn , lwd = 2, main="",
     ylab = expression("F(x)"),
     xlab=expression("x"),
     yaxt="n")
```

Comment: Thanks! it works but must use TeX("$F(x)$") instead of latex2exp("$F(x)$")

Comment: In fact, it works but doesn't render with the usual math font of latex.

Answer (score 1):

Edit:  Sorry, the answer below is for PDF output.  It's probably possible to do something similar for HTML output by processing the `tikz` figure into a PNG or SVG file and including that, but I haven't worked out the details.

You could try the `tikzDevice` package.  This example is based on Yihui's suggestion here:  https://github.com/daqana/tikzDevice/issues/60.

````
---
output:  
  pdf_document
header-includes:  
 - \usepackage{tikz}
---

```{r setup}
library(knitr)
knit_hooks$set(plot = function(x, options) {
  if ('tikz' %in% options$dev && !options$external) {
    hook_plot_tex(x, options)
  } else hook_plot_md(x, options)
})
```

Text.

```{r test, dev='tikz', external=FALSE}
x <- c(0,1,1,1,2,2,2,3)
Fn <- ecdf(x)
plot(Fn , lwd = 2, main="",ylab = "$F(x)$",xlab="$x$",yaxt="n")
```
````

Here's the output:

[image]

Comment: I use this solution for pdf outputs, I wanted for html. Thanks anyway ;)